# Check a closed cubic bezier curve path is on the inside of an ellipse

Tags: javascript, geometry, computational-geometry, bezier, adobe-illustrator

I am now scripting Illustrator by javascript.

Is it possible to check a closed path is on the inside of an ellipse? (As drawn in below picture, I wish to check a red path is on the inside of an ellipse)
A closed path is generally created by cubic bezier curve, in Illustrator.

[image: How to check a red path is on the inside of an ellipse, or not]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check, if all the control points of the curve are inside the ellipse. If so, your curve lies completely within the ellipse too.

Comment: Note that some control points could be outside the ellipse, but whole curve - inside it